# Cisco Meraki Indoor Localization

Tags: cisco, indoor-positioning-system

I'm going to realize a indoor positioning application using Cisco Meraki technology.

I've inserted the floor plan in the Meraki dashboard and activated the web server to manage the receive of the HTTP POST scanning API.

In the HTTP POST I obtained the latitude, longitude, x and y arrays and all of them have the same value for all connected devices despite devices are not in the exactly same position.

So my question is: 
is it possible to obtain the device's location with one only Access Point (only one Meraki MR33) or I need more APs?

Answer (score -1):

For mobile devices to be tracked properly, a minimum of three access points (with four or more preferred for better accuracy and precision) should be detecting and reporting the received signal strength (RSSI) of any client station, asset tag, or rogue device being tracked. It is preferred that this detected signal strength level be -75dBm or better.